# Want to make sense of array dimensions in logistic regression algorithms

Tags: machine-learning

I am trying to implement a simple logistic regression algorithm from scratch in python (for learning purposes). Every article I've seen online so far presents the following expression for $z$ (argument of the sigmoid function):

$$z = \theta^T\cdot x$$

However when they implement it in code they always use `np.dot(X, theta)` which is not the same thing. I have carefully tried to trace the dimensions of all the arrays as follows:

Dot product property: $\theta^T\cdot x = x^T\cdot\theta$

- $x$ is of dimension $l\times (d+1)$ where $l$ is the number of records and $d+1$ the number of features (including the $x_0$ ones vector).
- $\theta$ is of dimensions $1 \times (d+1)$ (every column in $x$ gets a weight, including the ones vector).
- $z$ is the dot product of $\theta^T$ and $x$, it will have dimensions $((d+1)\times 1)\cdot(l \times 1) =  ??$ --> **DOES NOT WORK**!

There appears to be no way to arrange the last statement such that it remains mathematically correct and yielding an array of dimension $l\times1$ or $1\times l$ without fundamentally changing either:

- the shape of $x$
- the equation itself (as they do in the code)

So which is correct? The code or the mathematical statement? Why are they contradictory? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Could you point at a reference for the sigmoid function that has the z=...? I'm looking at https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/4826/logistic-regression-with-python and https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-logistic-regression to get into the right area. Already reading this implementation https://github.com/Selim78/variance-reduction-methods as well.

Comment: In https://www.johnwittenauer.net/machine-learning-exercises-in-python-part-3/ I'm seeing them use "sigmoid(X * theta.T)" for their implementations.

Comment: It's almost certainly the case that $\theta^{T}x$ is supposed to be the dot product of two vectors (stored as column vectors.)

Answer (score 1):

They’re doing a dot product across each record using one call to `np.dot(.,.)`. They are doing this to take advantage of fast numpy operations on the whole dataset instead of having you loop through computing $z$ for each record individually using explicit Python code. They are essentially saying that $X = [x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n]^T$ and doing $Z = X \theta$ such that $Z = [z_1, \cdots, z_n]^T$ and $z_k = \theta^T x_k$.